# using FFMPEG, what is the lightest way to stream a mostly static picture? (in terms of bandwidth)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, bandwidth

I want to optimize a radio-like stream for youtube or twitch that features a progress-bar refreshing 5 times per second. Except for this progress-bar, the other parts of the video is static. Every 10 minutes or so, the stream moves on to a new track and the whole screen should change.

To make it crystal clear, here are a few illustrations of what the screen should look like.

The start of the track would be like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  First track name         +
+                ,          +
+  BG n⁰1     _ `|.         +
+            /o`=|          +
+     .=""=./::(.=""=.      +
+    /./.' .::::. \'. \     +
+   //\/ / :::::: \/\ \\    +
+  /\/ /\/\'::::'/\ \/\ \   +
+  /' `     '::'     ` `\   +
+           /::\            +
+          /\/\/\           +
+                           +
+  Progress-bar is below    +
+  |                   |    +
+                           +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

For 10 minutes or so, the only change would be in the progress-bar:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  First track name         +
+                ,          +
+  BG n⁰1     _ `|.         +
+            /o`=|          +
+     .=""=./::(.=""=.      +
+    /./.' .::::. \'. \     +
+   //\/ / :::::: \/\ \\    +
+  /\/ /\/\'::::'/\ \/\ \   +
+  /' `     '::'     ` `\   +
+           /::\            +
+          /\/\/\           +
+                           +
+  Progress-bar is below    +
+  |==========         |    +
+                           +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

When the track ends, after 10 minutes, the full image should change to display a new background:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  Second track name        +
+                           +
+  (the whole screen        +
+   should have refreshed)  +
+                           +
+  BG n⁰2        ,-.        +
+        ,      ( {o\       +
+        {`"=,___) (`~      +
+         \  ,_.-   )       +
+    ~^~^~^`- ~^ ~^ '~^~    +
+                           +
+                           +
+  Progress-bar is below    +
+  |                   |    +
+                           +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

---

To move on to the actual question, I have currently a solution that works with this ffmpeg command:

```
 ffmpeg -f x11grab -s "1280x720" -i :99.0+0,0 -f pulse -i default -f flv \
   -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1000k -maxrate 1360k -bufsize 1360k -g 60 -tune stillimage \
   -s "1280x720" -preset veryfast -vf "format=yuv420p" \
   "rtmp://SERVER_EITHER_YOUTUBE_OR_TWITCH/STREAM_KEY"
```

However this solution results in a relatively high bandwidth consumption:

- for one second, the upload is done with a rate of ~ 900-1000 KB/s
- for one second, the upload is done with a rate of ~ 1500-1600 KB/s

This pattern can be seen in the output of a `nload -t 100`, where each character corresponds to 100ms:

```
Device eth0 [xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz] (1/1):
====================================================================================
Incoming:
                                                               Curr: 60.77 kBit/s
                                                               Avg: 72.08 kBit/s
                                                               Min: 52.23 kBit/s
                                                               Max: 252.88 kBit/s
                                                               Ttl: 118.24 GByte
Outgoing:

   #||||..|||          #|.|||..|#          #|..|...|#          Curr: 1002.47 kBit/s
   ##########          ##########          ##########          Avg: 1.24 MBit/s
|#|##########.||||##|||##########.||#||##|.##########..||..||  Min: 749.30 kBit/s
#############################################################  Max: 8.83 MBit/s
#############################################################  Ttl: 92.46 GByte
```

I tried to reduce the bitrate but then the picture becomes noticeably blocky.

**In an ideal world**, this stream would be done with ten times less bandwidth:

- a picture of the screen (about 100 kB in png) uploaded every 2 seconds as a keyframe
- and otherwise less than 100 kB/s to transmit the audio and the small changes in the progress bar

**So the question is,** is there a ffmpeg setting compatible with the constraints of streaming services (one keyframe every 2 seconds) that could achieve lower bandwidth while keeping high quality?

---

---

---

**EDIT** I tried to use the `-crf 23` option, the ffmpeg command becoming like this:

```
 ffmpeg -f x11grab -s "1280x720" -i :99.0+0,0 -f pulse -i default -f flv \
   -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -g 60 -tune stillimage \
   -s "1280x720" -preset veryfast -vf "format=yuv420p" \
   "rtmp://SERVER_EITHER_YOUTUBE_OR_TWITCH/STREAM_KEY"
```

On the good side, the bandwidth did diminish and that's an improvement. But I still see this rectangular signal, with one second of low bandwidth consumption at 300 KB/s and one second of high consumption at 1300 KB/s.

```
 Device eth0 [xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz] (1/1):                                                 
 =================================================================================
 Incoming:
                                                                 Curr: 76.65 kBit/
                                                                 Avg: 76.11 kBit/s
                                                                 Min: 10.08 kBit/s
                                                                 Max: 9.78 MBit/s
                                                                 Ttl: 118.88 GByte
 Outgoing:
 
                                                                 Curr: 1.26 MBit/s
  ||||||||||          |||||||||          ||||||||||          ||  Avg: 1.09 MBit/s
  ##########          ##########         ##########          ##  Min: 55.66 kBit/s
  ##########         |##########         ##########          ##  Max: 10.86 MBit/s
 ####################################|||#######################  Ttl: 103.00 GByte
```

Comment: Why set a bitrate? Try with -crf 23

Comment: Live stream sites (and especially twitch) typically what strict CBR for easier resource allocation.  Spiky bitrates requires overallocation to be able to serve the peak.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan I tried your suggestion and it results in a lower bandwidth consumption while keeping a great quality (see edits). Do you have any idea how to remove the "rectangular pattern" shape?

Comment: @szatmary thanks for the comment, I kind of tried to have a constant bitrate allocation with my command by specifying `-b:v 1000k -maxrate 1360k -bufsize 1360k`. Do you have a suggestion to achieve CBR while maintaining a low bitrate (using ffmpeg)?